# Скрыть элемент, если нет на странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть блок:

```
<form Id="add">
</form>
```

Вызывается он из другого скрипта и если проверка проходит то блок есть, если нет -  форма просто не загружается.

Внизу страницы есть дубль кнопки которая участвует в этой форме.
Как на jQuery сделать проверку - чтобы скрыть дублирующую кнопку, если форма не загружена?

Если `#add` есть на странице, то показывать кнопку `#down-add`,
если нет такого `id`, то `#down-add` - скрывать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083147/div-display-if-block-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// скрипт выполнять после загрузки (ну или НЕ загрузки) вашей формы
if(!$('#add').length) { // если нет этой кнопки
  $('#down-add').hide() // скрываем. Открывать ничего не нужно, ведь у вас и так она открыта. 
}
// ну или наоборот, css'ом скрывайте изначально button, а проверку поменяйте
if($('#add').length) { // если нет этой кнопки
  $('#down-add').show()
}
```

Comment: спасибо! решено!